# How to prevent EF6 from falling back to "dbo" schema, when a service (with a custom DB schema name) is restarted?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-6

I have a EntityFramework 6.2.0 based Service (has API + UI) that uses a custom DB Schema name. The DbContext does not belong to me, but comes from a 3rd party library.

A strange issue happens when the service hasn't been initialized or accessed yet, due to a redeployment, IIS or AppPool reset etc, in which case, if I call the Application first, which then invokes the service, then for whatever reason, the service defaults to expecting a "dbo" schema. The "dbo" schema doesn't exist and I never created it. I have a custom schema for the service. So the service complains that it did not find my table under "dbo" schema and fails to return results, totally ignoring what I have specified as the schema name in code.

To fix this, I have make sure every time, that before the application calls the service, I first warm up the service, by hitting its UI or API endpoints first. When I do this, the service picks up my Custom Schema name and it works fine. So when my application calls this pre-initialized service, it is able to find the tables under my Custom Schema and returns results.

The only difference in these two cases is that, the service can work with the database only if it was invoked separately first, followed by subsequent application calls. However, if it was initialized as a result of a first call from application, it goes looking for "dbo" schema and complains when it doesn't find a table under "dbo" schema.

I tried setting `Database.SetInitializer<MyDbContext>(null);` to disable automatic migrations but that didn't work. I also have set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;` for the Migration Configuration class.

Since the DbContext resides in a 3rd party library I cannot do: `modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("myschema");`

The only place that I could find the string "dbo" getting mentioned is the ".resx" file of my first migration (I only have one right now). I assume it was auto-generated when I called "Add-Migration".

I haven't tried changing the ".resx" file DefaultSchema entry manually, as the migration is already applied, and it would be a dirty trick even if it worked.

Is there a way to control the schema name when calling "Add-Migration"?

```
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred 
while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. 
---> 
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'dbo.MyTable'.
```